# What is that for a huge bridge on a Les Paul?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, bridge

I am really interested into the bridge of this Les Paul. So far I have not seen such a bridge. Unfortunately I could not find the name of the guitarist. The music video can be found [here](https://youtu.be/XepU-W76TNk).

[image: Guitar]
<sub>Click on the image to enlarge.</sub>

What are the features of this bridge and are there other guitars that have the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bridge is a Washburn Wonderbar system, as used by Ace Frehley during his Washburn endorsee years. He subsequently had one fitted to his Les Paul during that time, my belief is this is a guitar owned by a fan looking to emulate his Les Paul - the 12th fret inlay is that of the Epiphone signature model from the 90s which Ace has never played live.

It has a cork screw spring within and the system can bolt onto the surface of any solid body guitar. No need for a traditional tremolo cut through. Perfect for retaining the sustain of a heavy solid Les Paul